# Input text field tp accept unlimited characters

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on wordpress. I have a scenario to sort post in zipcodes. What I have done is I have made every zipcode a category. My ZIP code list is extremely long and contain more than 32369 character. When I paste that text in input field it just rip off the text to 32369 characters. Is there any solution of it?. As its all wordpress default so I cant change input type text to textarea by changing the code but yes a jquery solution might work.

I have tried on other input text boxes too but got same result i-e display 32369 character and then rip off the remaining text.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do (UX wise), but please don't.

Comment: [offtopic] Maybe you could split your post into a series of smaller posts, e.g. ZIP-codes of Europe, Asia, Northern America, etc.

Comment: I want input text field to accept more then 32369 characters

Comment: Just saw your display picture. Nice way to say impossible :)

Comment: For a text input, the max character length is 524288, i'm sure you're trying to save that data to mysql and due to the varchar column definition, it's being truncated. I would suggest an alternate method for storing this data.